# Best algorithm for copying selected rows of a Swing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jython-2.7

I am trying to copy the selected lines of a JTable Swing, using Jython. Copy event happens on click, so the starting point are the selected lines, and the final goal is to copy them under them. 
I tried, but I came up with an "extremely" onerous algorithm that does not do exactly what I want (copy over the selected ones, not below...!)

```
def copySelectedLine(self, e):
   model = self.table.getModel()
   dataVector = model.getDataVector()
   rowsToCopy = self.table.getSelectedRows()
   for adder, r in enumerate(rowsToCopy):
      r = r+adder
      newDataVector = dataVector[:r] + [([model.getValueAt(r, c) for c in xrange(3)] + [
         '', '', '', '', '', ''])] + dataVector[r:] # personal concatenation
      model.setRowCount(0)
      for nr in newDataVector:
         model.addRow(nr)
```

I accept a suggestion also in Java. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean have something like rows A, B, C, D and if A and C are copied you then want A, A', B, C, C', D?

Comment: Exactly @Thomas!!

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger already? If not I suggest you do so. Btw, I'm no Python developer and I don't know Jython as well so I can't really comment on your code but doesn't indentation describe blocks? Thus your code looks like it's nesting the loops to build the new model and to reset the model. That could be the issue with your code. Also I don't know if `setRowCount(0)` will actually truncate the data vector you got (and delete thw rows) so you might need to make a copy of the existing rows before calling that method.

Comment: @Thomas Resolved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simplicity is the hardest thing* cit. Massimiliano Allegri

```
def copySelectedLine(self, e):
   model = self.table.getModel()
   rowsToCopy = self.table.getSelectedRows()
   for adder, r in enumerate(rowsToCopy):
      i = r+adder+1
      model.insertRow(i, [model.getValueAt(r, c) for c in xrange(3)])
```

PS: Strange that I was the first to answer...